# How to step through edited code of a sub-module/lib via IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, artifactory

Am using JDK 1.8 w/ IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 Ultimate Edition on macOS Big Sur 11.6.1.

The situation is that I have a main Java based Spring Boot Microservice that I import as a Maven project.

However, there's a particular lib that is a dependency (its listed in the `<dependencies>` section of that Spring Boot Microservice's `pom.xml` file) which I need to be able to put either `System.out.println()` or `logger.info()` (`logback.xml`) statements into...

When I `git clone` both Maven projects (the Spring Boot Microservice & the particular lib that I need to debug), I do the following process:

1. After a fresh `git clone`of both projects in separate folders, I first import the main Spring Boot Microservice as a Maven Project inside IntelliJ.
2. Go to File --> Project Structure and then click on the `+` sign and import the dependency lib (which I wish to edit the code with printlns and/or log statements) as as Module (Maven project).
3. Put breakpoints and `log.info()` statements in key sections of the dependency lib's codebase and issue a `mvn clean install` from either IntellIJ via a run config and/or from the command line.
4. `mvn clean install` (even tried `mvn clean install -nsu`) within the Spring Boot Microservice's top-level project folder and then Run in debug mode (with breakpoints inside the particular endpoint REST Controller class or service impl class, inside the Spring Boot Microservice's codebase which I know will use the dependent lib), the Spring Boot application containing its `main()` method.

What happens is when I hit the REST endpoint via Postman or curl, I am able to step through the dependent lib's codebase via the IntelliJ's debugger but only from the one that is inside the compiled jar (which comes downloaded from Artifactory into my local `~/.m2/repository`) and not the codebase which I imported as a module (which contains my `printlns` to stdout and/or my `log.info()` statements), the step through debug process only shows the original unchanged code from GitHub.

Does anyone know how to make it step through that dependent lib's source code (which I edited and then conducted a `mvn clean install`) so I can see my local changes (calls to stdout and/or `log.info()` statements) ?

Comment: Your question hard is to understand. Show few screenshot.

Comment: @DoNhuVy - sorry, what I have is proprietary and can't replicate this with sample code unless I push it to the remote Artifactory repo (which I am not allowed to put sample projects into). Think of it as debugging through a Java lib but wishing to see the log and/or print statements of that "edited & locally built" Java lib but not the unchanged codebase which is downloaded during `mvn clean install` from Artifactory.

Comment: If you changed the lib code do you have changed the version and change the version used in your project accordingly?

Comment: I have it set as a sub module via IntelliJ. I put breakpoints but the Debugger only steps through the downloaded original jar file of that lib instead of the one that I locally built. The debugger does hit the specific breakpoints in the original code but not the changed lib.